# Is assignment in a conditional clause good ruby style?

Tags: ruby, coding-style

In order to write more concisely, rather than do this:

```
test_value = method_call_that_might_return_nil()
if test_value
  do_something_with test_value
end
```

I've been assigning in the conditional:

```
if test_value = method_call_that_might_return_nil()
  do_something_with test_value
end
```

Is this bad style? The still-more-concise syntax:

```
do_something_with test_value if test_value = method_call_that_might_return_nil()
```

is not allowed, as discussed [in another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380331/conditional-statement-and-assigning-value-in-ruby), and will remain that way in 1.9, according to Matz (http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/show/1141).

Given the possible confusion of assignment and comparison, does this make it too hard to read the code?

Comment: I think a line must be drawn between conciseness and understandability. I think in today's time, where we must know several different languages, its a good idea to use cool new features of certain languages without damaging existing programmer knowledge real-estate. As an expert programmer, why should I have the need to google such syntactical suitableness from language to language? I would much rather spend time googling about the problem at hand. For example, how to multithread in ruby.

Comment: Rubocop and this ruby style guide recommend avoiding it: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide

Comment: Link to the specific part of the style guide: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#safe-assignment-in-condition

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It is GOOD style to use assignments in conditionals. If you do so, wrap the condition in parentheses.

```rb
# bad (+ a warning)
if v = array.grep(/foo/)
  do_something(v)
  # some code
end

# good (MRI would still complain, but RuboCop won't)
if (v = array.grep(/foo/))
  do_something(v)
  # some code
end

# good
v = array.grep(/foo/)
if v
  do_something(v)
  # some code
end
```

[See the community style guide for more information](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#safe-assignment-in-condition)

Comment: While this works, I get a `warning: found = in conditional, should be ==`

Comment: Can somebody explain why the 1st one (without parenthesis) is BAD, please?

Comment: @KenRatanachaiS. The reason it's bad is because it's usually the case that you are doing a straight up equality check in a conditional (with `==`), and assignment (`=`) is a common typo. Requiring surrounding parentheses when you do assignment in conditional is an extra hint to the reader that the assignment was INTENTIONAL, not a typo.

Comment: @DevonParsons Thanks. So it's to avoid typo. But sometime assignments in IF condition give me unexpected result as well. May be Scoping problem.

Comment: Can someone shed light on the scope of assigned variable in a condition, can it be accessed outside the conditional block?

Comment: @Murphy yes, variables that are brought into scope in a conditional assignment OR in the conditional blocks are both available after the conditional scope ends.

Answer (score 29):

One *somewhat* widespread idiom is to use `and`, which would look something like this:

```
tmp = method_call_that_might_return_nil and do_something_with tmp
```

Another possibility would be to call `#nil?` explicitly, that way the intent becomes a little bit clearer; in particular it is really obvious that you actually *meant* to assign instead of compare:

```
unless (tmp = method_call_that_might_return_nil).nil?
  do_something_with tmp
end
```

Answer (score 10):

Concise code is not necessarily better code.  Concision is useful when it improves the communication of intended code behavior from author to future maintainers.  I think enough of us come from backgrounds in which we've had accidental assignments in `if` blocks (when we meant to have an equality comparison) that we prefer styles in which it's absolutely clear that assignment is meant, rather than comparison.  The `.nil?` idiom already mentioned has that property, and I'd consider it cleaner than having the bare assignment inside the `if` condition.  Really, though, I don't see the harm in having the extra line of code for the assignment.

Answer (score 5):

The functional-programming way to do this is to use [`andand`](http://andand.rubyforge.org/). It's a readable way of chaining method calls so that a nil in the middle stops the chain. So your example would be something like:

```
method_call_that_might_return_nil.andand.tap {|obj| do_something_with obj}
## or, in the common case: ##
method_call_that_might_return_nil.andand.do_something
```

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I would say it's bad style due to the possible confusion between assignment and comparison. It's only one more line to assign and then test, and it avoids having someone in the future think that was a bug and patch it to use `==` instead.

Answer (score 2):

C programmers do this a lot. I don't see a problem with it in Ruby either so long as it's clear what's happening.

Comment: The problem is that ruby gives a warning whenever you assign in a conditional. If it didn't, I suspect it would be as popular in ruby as it is in C.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's fine.  Aversion to assignment in a condition comes from knowing that a missed key stroke when typing == turns a comparison into an unintended assignment.  A stylistic prohibition on using assignment in a condition makes such accidents stand out like to the eye (and sometimes to the language, as in C, where many compilers can be made to emit a warning if they encounter an assignment in a condition).  On the other hand, tests also make such accidents stand out.  If your code is well covered by tests, you can consider discarding such prohibitions.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the warning, performing the assignment in the `if` clause has a quite pungent smell. If you do have an `else` case to handle then the `case ... in ...` pattern matching can offer something:

```
case method_call_that_might_return_nil
in nil
  # handle nil case
in test_value # pattern match to a new variable 
  # handle non-nil case with return value of method assigned to test_value
end
```

Or...

```
case method_call_that_might_return_nil
in test_value if test_value # pattern match to a new variable if not nil
  # handle non-nil case with return value of method assigned to test_value
else
  # handle nil case
end
```