# Prevent variable binding to nil in Ruby pattern matching?

Tags: ruby, pattern-matching

When utilizing the new `case ... in` [pattern matching in Ruby](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0.0/doc/syntax/pattern_matching_rdoc.html), is there a nice way to prevent binding of `nil` to a variable?

```
case method()
in ... # Some cases here
  ...
in ...
  ...
in variable # If previous clauses did not match, then capture to variable
  puts variable
else # How to prevent that variable also captures nil?
  puts "Nil" # -> This is not called if method() returns nil
end
```

I have found the following two ways but they kind of seem ugly:

1.) Use `if` qualifier

```
case method()
in ... # Some cases here
  ...
in ...
  ...
in variable if variable
  puts variable
else 
  puts "Nil"
end
```

2.) Reverse match order

```
case method()
in ... # Some cases here
  ...
in ...
  ...
in nil
  puts "Nil"
in variable # Catch all
  puts variable
end
```

Is there something nicer?

---

How could this also be used? It would allow a nice way to do comparison and assignment against `nil` using the one-line pattern matching expression:

```
if method() => variable
  ... 
end
```

(This question was inspired by [a question on assignments in if statements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1966585/278842))

Comment: Does adding an explicit pattern match for `NilClass` work?

Comment: `NilClass` and `nil` can both be used interchangeably here, but I would like something like `in variable: !NilClass`

Comment: Readers: I was perplexed by seeing `in` rather than `when` in the `case` statement. I soon discovered that this *pattern matching* was introduced in v2.7, whilst the documentation evidently first appeared for v3.0.0. If this is new to you as well you may find [this article](https://www.toptal.com/ruby/ruby-pattern-matching-tutorial) provides a helpful introduction.

Comment: IMO your second option looks pretty decent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Match NilClass Without Assignment

If you've decided that `nil` should be ignored, you can do it by simply matching against NilClass and then not assigning the result. Do this before calling your as-pattern (e.g. `in variable`) or an else clause. For example:

```
# arg can be assigned `nil` but can't be unassigned; this
# ensures that any nil values were actually passed in
def pattern_match arg
  case arg
  in /^a$/ => bar
  in NilClass
  in bar
  end

  # We print a message here to differentiate between arg and
  # bar being `nil`, because otherwise the method simply
  # returns `nil` since bar is auto-vivified by the
  # interpreter when it evaluates the case statement. This is
  # a potential source of confusion when looking at the
  # results.
  bar || 'matched NilClass'
end

# pass values through a scope gate for testing each
# assignment to bar in isolation
[?a, 'str', 1, nil].map { pattern_match _1 }
#=> ["a", "str", 1, "matched NilClass"]
```

Comment: Since NilClass has only a single(ton) instance, why not use `nil` directly?

Comment: @ChristopherOezbek Because `case` uses the case equality operator, not standard equality, and I find that `NilClass === arg` expresses my intent more clearly than `nil == nil`. Note that you can also pattern match against String, Integer, and so forth, so using NilClass explicitly makes a useful example. Your semantic intent may vary, but in this particular case the net result will be the same either way.