# Ruby syntax oddity

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [conditional statement and assigning value in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380331/conditional-statement-and-assigning-value-in-ruby)

While refactoring some rails code, I have encountered some syntax oddity in ruby.

Given the following method

```
def get_value
  42
end
```

Why does this work?

```
if value = get_value
  puts value
end
```

While this does not?

```
puts value if value = get_value
```

The latter gives an error: `` undefined local variable or method `value' for main:Object (NameError) ``. I thought these expressions were equal? When the if-block is evaluated before the puts, `value` should not be undefined.

Comment: I know this is a dup but can't find it

Comment: [This answer should help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4500597/499609).

Comment: @DGM: I had the exact same feeling! I just spent the last 9 minutes searching for a dupe, and none seemed to come up.

Comment: [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2291646/in-ruby-why-wont-foo-true-unless-definedfoo-make-the-assignment) should also be helpful.

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380331/conditional-statement-and-assigning-value-in-ruby

Comment: if value = get_value statement will always return get_value so it will always be true

Comment: It can't run the line until it has *parsed* the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's due to the parsing of lines, vs execution time.  In the first version, value is parsed and set and then the puts evaluated.  In the second line, when the parser gets to the variable `puts value`, it has not yet been defined.   In other words, it can't *run* the line to set the variable, until it has first *parsed* the line.